# logstash 5.0.0.1 RHEL6 wont start

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

A Clean RHEL 6.0, Can you please tell me what am i missing.
i have done the following but seems to be some where i am going wrong cat start logstash for some reason.

i am not a newbe to linux. trying to learn as i go.

have done the following to get the install working.

Elasticsearch and Kibana start fine problem is with the Logstash.

hope some one can help me out here. really stuck to get this one working.

```
#Install Java
    sudo su -c "yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk"

*Installed:
  java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64 1:1.8.0.45-28.b13.el6_6
**Complete**!*

    java -version


*openjdk version "1.8.0_45"*


#Install elasticsearch
sudo su -c "yum localinstall elasticsearch-5.0.1.rpm "


*Running Transaction
  Installing : elasticsearch-5.0.1-1.noarch                                                                                                                                                                1/1
Creating elasticsearch group... OK
Creating elasticsearch user... OK
NOT starting on installation, please execute the following statements to configure elasticsearch service to start automatically using chkconfig
sudo chkconfig --add elasticsearch
 You can start elasticsearch service by executing
sudo service elasticsearch start
  Verifying  : elasticsearch-5.0.1-1.noarch                                                                                                                                                                1/1
Installed:
  elasticsearch.noarch 0:5.0.1-1*

**Complete**!

    sudo chkconfig --add elasticsearch
    sudo service elasticsearch start

* elasticsearch Started*

#Install kibana

    sudo su -c "yum localinstall kibana-5.0.1-x86_64.rpm"

*Downloading Packages:
Installed:
  kibana.x86_64 0:5.0.1-1*

**Complete**!


#Install logstash
sudo su -c "yum localinstall logstash-5.0.1.rpm"


*Total size: 189 M
  Installing : 1:logstash-5.0.1-1.noarch                                                                                                                                                                   1/1
Using provided startup.options file: /etc/logstash/startup.options
Successfully created system startup script for Logstash
  Verifying  : 1:logstash-5.0.1-1.noarch                                                                                                                                                                   1/1
Installed:
  logstash.noarch 1:5.0.1-1*

**Complete!**



#Query config values

    rpm -qc elasticsearch


*/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml
/etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options
/etc/elasticsearch/log4j2.properties
/etc/elasticsearch/scripts
/etc/init.d/elasticsearch
/etc/sysconfig/elasticsearch
/usr/lib/sysctl.d/elasticsearch.conf
/usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service*



#Query config values

    rpm -qc logstash

*/etc/logstash/jvm.options
/etc/logstash/logstash.yml
/etc/logstash/startup.options*


#Query config values
    rpm -qc kibana
*/etc/kibana/kibana.yml*

#Permissions

    sudo su -c "chmod -R 777 /etc/kibana/"
    sudo su -c "chmod -R 777 /etc/logstash/"
    sudo su -c "chmod -R 777 /etc/elasticsearch/"

    sudo service kibana start

*-- output kibana started*

Grrr..... This does not stat

sudo chkconfig --add logstash
    sudo service logstash start
> try this ->

    sudo su -c "/usr/share/logstash/bin/system-install"


* Sending all logs to /tmp/tmp.ZNfIKnQxFh Successfully created system
startup script for Logstash*
```

Comment: Could post the exact error you get when you're starting logstash?

Comment: its not insalling the service.